# Timer Fires->Audio File Does Not Play Cleanly

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I am writing a Windows Phone 8 application and am trying to play an audio file (in this case Metronome920.wav, a 0.07s, 6kb file) when a timer fires. The file plays when the timer fires, but probably 40-50% of the time, when it plays, it crackles/pops and does not play cleanly. The application is very simple, and only incorporates the timer/audio playback. I have not changed the GUI from the default GUI created when I started the new project in Visual Studio.

This leads me to believe that this may be a threading issues. Any ideas?

```
namespace AudioTest1
{
    class MyTimer
    {
        private Timer t; //Windows.Threading.Timer

        public MyTimer()
        {
            t = new Timer(new TimerCallback(timer_Tick), null, 0, 500);
        }

        private void PlaySound()
        {
            using (var stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream("Sounds\\Metronome920.wav"))
            {
                var effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream);
                FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
                effect.Play();
            }
        }
        private void timer_Tick(object sender)
        {
                PlaySound();
        }

    }
}
```

I am creating a MyTimer object from the following code in MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyTimer m = new MyTimer();
    }
```

Edit: Audio file of what's happening when run on the device is at the following location: [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/19973192/winphone8sound.mp3)

Comment: Is the behavior different in the emulator vs. on a physical device? Also, have you considered using the MediaElement rather than a SoundEffect?

Comment: I just created a sample project using your code, but with my own "metronome.wav" file and it works perfectly on my machine.  Listenting to it tick away in the background as I write this.

Comment: I am running this on one of the new Nokia phones. Have not tried it on the emulator, as I expected performance to be degraded vs. on a phone. I tried using a MediaElement as well, but seemed to run into the same problem.

Comment: @BStateham, are you using the emulator, or a device?

Comment: Interesting, just tried it on the emulator, and it worked much better. Will investigate further.

Comment: I have posted an audio file of the sound heard from the phone here:[sound file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/19973192/winphone8sound.mp3)

Comment: I was able to get similar results to yours on my own phone.  I noticed that while my phone was plugged in and I had done some debugging, ANY sounds (even system sounds) were sputtery.  I tried disconnecting the phone, powering it down COMPLETELY, then bringing it back up. The sounds tick reliably now.  Now, I did make a change to using a DispatchTimer instead of a regular timer (just seeing if that made a difference) but you might try a hard power off/on on your physical device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try doing a hard shutdown / restart of your phone device.  I was having results similar to yours, then once I did a hard reset of the device the stuttering sounds stopped.  I tried this with a regular Timer, a DispatcherTimer and with a MediaElement instead of a SoundEffect.  You can grab my sample solution here: http://sdrv.ms/Rfb7UM

Comment: Great response. Thank you for both looking into this issue and providing sample code! The restart definitely helped, and I will also make tweaks to my code based on your suggestions/samples.

Comment: I have been playing with my three samples, and it seems like the DispatcherTimer and SoundEffect works the best.  Your mileage may vary.

Comment: I agree, that combination seems to be the best choice on my device as well. Thank you again!